# Create Specific Uername and Password, Just for One Specific Database in MYSQL

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp

i have several database in phpmyadmin.but i want to set Specific username and password for one of them.in the way that, only with this username and password can be connected to the this Specific database.
for example:

host => localhost

user => admin

pass => 1111

dbName => mydatabase

and no one can't access to this database with default username and password (user: 'root' & pass: '')

what should i do??? in addition i am using xampp.

please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can change the password or even rename the user; that would keep people from logging in through that account.

Aside from that, I'm pretty confident that any superuser (a user with all privileges) cannot be blocked from a database. You probably don't want to remove all superuser accounts, either, so you're pretty much restricted to making it an account that only you know about. You could, if you really wanted, then create a new "root" account with restricted permissions, but for the sake of not confusing everyone that's probably a bad idea. I'd just set the password for root to something secret, then give everyone else access to a more restricted account.